# Can't get default values into directive from parent component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having difficulty getting default values into my directive as set by the parent component.

Here's the instance of my directive, mrc-input-field, which lives in paymentform.html:

```
<mrc-input-field id="mrc-quantity" label="Quantity" data="$ctrl.quantity" type="number" ></mrc-input-field2>
```

and here's the resulting (relevant) markup emitted by mrcInputField;

```
<input id="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" ng-model="$ctrl.data" placeholder="Quantity" >
```

$ctrl.quantity is set by the parent paymentform.js and I have data bound in the directive;

```
.directive("mrcInputField", mrcInputField2);

mrcInputField.$inject = ['$compile', '_'];

function mrcInputField($compile, _) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        data: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
```

yet the form has quantity blank when I open it.  The good part is that it works for getting the input values out of the directive, i.e.  my paymentform.js is getting the entered quantity from the mrc-input-field directive.

The directive is generating and $compile'ing the resulting markup i.e. the input element above.

Thanks for any clues

Update: I didn't mention, the problem is that the value of the "data" inside the directive is the string value "$ctrl.quantity" instead of the value of $ctrl.quantity (which is number 1).

Comment: how you are saying that you haven't got any value for `data` inside directive?

Comment: Well, the value for data inside the directive is "$ctrl.quantity" instead of the value that $ctrl.quantity contains.

Comment: create a plunk that represents this problem, i do not see any problem in provided code...